# Magento custom attribute check on cart/checkout page (show/hide shipping method) based on specific attribute selected in backend

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, php

I was figuring out a way to write a functionality that can check on my cart/checkout page (**Magento 1.9x**) custom attribute either based on **YES/NO** selected from the backend of that particular product should produce specific action.

The main purpose of writing this code was to restrict people in California purchasing specific products which are not compliant. I hope it helps!

**Directory to look for:**
`design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml`

**Full working code snippet is shown below with appropriate comments:**

```
<?php 

//loads selected shipping state
$shippingst= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getRegion(); 

//loads quote in cart variable
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();

//loop to handle all items in cart
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {

//loading product attribute code  
$productAtt= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId())->getres_california();
    
//condition that checks selected region is california and product restricted attribute code is true    
if ($shippingst=='California' && $productAtt=='1') {

//Perform here whatever action is required on checkout page

echo "<style>#shipping-method-buttons-container{display:none;}.sp-methods{display:none;}</style>";

echo $shippingst.": <b>Restricted</b><br>";

echo "We're sorry cart contains product restricted in california";

echo "<br><a href='/checkout/cart/' class='button_cart_restricted'>Check your cart</a>";

        break; //dont break the loop if you want to repeat action for each product in cart.

    }
    

    else {echo "";}

      }

?>
```

`$productAtt` loads the attribute code, Where `res_california` is the attribute code value taken out from backend of magento.

[image]